# Is it possible to skip tests in HSpec test suite?

Tags: haskell, hspec

In most programming languages it is easy to skip a test in some circumstances. Is there a proper way to do that in haskell HSpec based test suite?

Comment: What is the connection between the programming language and testing system? :)

Comment: I meant implementation of test cases, which usually imply applying of a testing framework.

Comment: it looks like there is now also an option to skip tests when running in a similar way to `-m` https://hspec.github.io/options.html `--skip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, *Core* of *HSpec* doesn't have a special solution for this case. But you can skip tests without verbosity about it. For example:

```
main = hspec $ do
    ...
    when isDatabaseServerRunning $ do
        describe "database" $ do
            it "test some one" $ do
                ...
```

Another solution maybe to use the function like `mapSpecItem_` for changing result of test to `Pending` with a message about why was skipped. For example:

```
skip :: String -> Bool -> SpecWith a -> SpecWith a
skip   _ False = id
skip why True  = mapSpecItem_ updateItem
  where
    updateItem x = x{itemExample = \_ _ _ -> return . Pending . Just $ why}
```

Comment: > If I understand correctly, Core of HSpec doesn't have a special solution for this case.



Thank you @freestyle, that confirms my assumption

Comment: Isn't the `xit` function relevant here? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-2.7.0/docs/Test-Hspec.html#v:xit

Comment: @RonyHe Yes, but `xit` was added after I wrote the answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

> Changing `it` to `xit` marks the corresponding spec item as pending

source:
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-2.11.7/docs/Test-Hspec.html#v:xit

Comment: It'd be great if `xit` had additional `String` parameter to describe why the test is skipped. Right now, using `xit` results in `# PENDING: No reason given`.

Comment: it may have this `string` parameter now https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec-2.11.7/docs/Test-Hspec.html#v:xit